# iPad black launch image for iPhone only app

Tags: ipad, ios7, xcode5.1

I've created a brand new iPhone only application and added in the launch images for 2x and R4. This runs fine on the iPhone (4S and above) but if I run the application on an iPad or iPad mini then the launch image is black.

I am using XCode 5.1.1 and running the app on iOS 7.1.2 on an iPad mini using Image Assets to hold the images. I've tried adding images for the iPad portrait (1x and 2x) as well but still comes up as black.

Any tips in how to make the launch image for an iPhone app show up when running on an iPad or iPad mini?

Comment: You create application for iPhone only, why do you have to care about iPad?

Comment: because peple can still run it on the iPad.